# Two threads and 1 service, or a service per thread?

Tags: android, performance, service, android-asynctask

Well.. what I'm trying to do here is implement something like a peer-to-peer client. Being that, it will start a client thread and a server thread.

I know Services themselves run in the main GUI thread, so I'll have to start a couple of independent threads (or Asynctasks?) for each server and client. The only thing I'm not so sure about is if I'll better have 1 Service starting 2 threads, or maybe 2 services, each one of them starting their own thread.

What do you think? which way is better perfomance-wise? or is it irrelevant?

Thanks
Nelson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance-wise, it's irrelevant.

So it all depends on the semantics of your two tasks, and how much code you'd share, etc. Maybe having a `BilthonService` spanning a `ClientThread` and `ServerThread` is not too bad, given that the service class itself will barely have any code.

Answer (score 1):

You should read [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#procthread) chapter from [Android Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) if you have not yet read.

Each service should span it's own thread. When each new request is recepted span a new thread dedicated for that communication. This way you can handle multiple request in the same time on your server.

Comment: Well yes.. I've read that chapter, but it doesn't say anything explicit about a service spanning 2 or more threads.

Comment: In order to server each request in the same time you need to have it running in separate threads.